# Python: CSV File to Dictionary without csv module

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I know there are many other questions out there with the answer to this, but I want to know how to read a CSV file into a nested dictionary. So it would go from something like this:

```
    '''"YEAR","GENDER","NAME","COUNT"
    "2011","FEMALE","A","100"
    "2012","FEMALE","A","50"
    "2012","FEMALE","B","10"
    "2012","FEMALE","C","10"
    "2012","FEMALE","D","5"
    "2013","FEMALE","A","1000"
    '''
```

To something like this:

```
{('B', 'FEMALE'): {2012: (10, None)}, 
 ('C', 'FEMALE'): {2012: (10, None)}, 
 ('A', 'FEMALE'): {2011: (100, None), 
                   2012: (50, None), 
                   2013: (1000, None)}, 
 ('D', 'FEMALE'): {2012: (5, None)}}
```

But I need to do it without importing anything, so I can't use the CSV module. And this is a general example; I'd need the code to work for multiple cases that could be longer or shorter than this one.

(There are 11 files total, this being one of them, and the text here is exactly as it is in the file:

```
    "YEAR","GENDER","NAME","COUNT"
    "2011","FEMALE","A","100"
    "2012","FEMALE","A","50"
    "2012","FEMALE","B","10"
    "2012","FEMALE","C","10"
    "2012","FEMALE","D","5"
    "2013","FEMALE","A","1000"
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, why can't you import anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    infile.readline()  # we don't care about the header row
    for line in infile:
        year, gender, name, count = (s.strip('"') for s in line.split(','))
        key = (name, gender)
        if key not in answer: answer[key] = {}
        answer[key][int(year)] = (int(count), None)
```

Comment: Sorry, new to this and didn't notice the small add a comment button. I downvoted because the code just gave me value errors when I tested it.

Comment: @jtdurb96: if you could show me your error, I'd be happy to update my answer

Comment: Well, one value error said "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)" and the other seven say "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" and then the number for count in quotes.

Comment: The code I gave you works on the document you posted. Please edit your original post to include a representative sample of the input

Comment: So I tried bringing back up the errors I had before on the command prompt, but now the error is the same for all of them, saying "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." My code is exactly as you typed it, except for it all being used to define a function.

Comment: @jtdurb96: you didn't copy the code correctly. You have an indentation error in your function's code. That's what's causing your issue

Comment: thanks, that fixed that. But I still get the other two value errors. And could you elaborate on including a "representative sample of the input"?

Comment: @jtdurb96: the code that I have provided works for the sample input in your question. However, there seem to be lines in your actual input that significantly differ from the input that you've shown us. This means that despite the fact that my code works for the input you've posted, it won't necessarily work for your actual input file. Therefore, please post a section of your actual input file (which demonstrates the error), so that I can fix my code